# Install ASP.Net MVC Nuget Package with NetCore App 1.0 on Visual Studio 2015 Update3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I need to install Microsoft ASP Net MVC Nuget Package as reference on my project, I am using Microsoft Net Core App 1.0.1 on Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. Using Nuget Package Manager I found the 5.2.3 version of MVC Package but I got this error:

> Package Microsoft.Mvc.5.2.3 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0
>   The same is with WebPages,Razor and Infrastructure packages.

I have already tried with older version of the same package but still got the same error.

I have been googling this error but I did not find useful info, in fact, many pages are focused on 2.0 version of NetCore.

My question is: what am I missing in order to install MVC in my project? how can I solve the not compatible message?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can't use MVC 5 with .NET Core. And why are you using a 3 year old IDE?

Comment: @mason because Visual Studio is too costly. :|

Comment: Really? If you work alone or in a small company, then [Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) is likely free for you. Or [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is always free. You can either to develop .NET Core apps.